# Node JS redirects give me a bunch of html text

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, render

Would like to ask a question regarding nodeJS redirects and maybe rendering.

**app.js**

In my app.js, I have these codes, which works well.

```
app.get('/dashboard', routes.dashboard);
app.get('/error/404', error.notFound);
```

Then, going further into the methods of

**error.notFound**

Which works well too when you load it from the URL

```
exports.illegal = function(req, res){
    var authLevel = '';
    var entityName = '';
    var entityId = '';
    var deviceId = '';

    if (req.session.authorizationLevel) authLevel = req.session.authorizationLevel;
    if (req.session.name) entityName = req.session.name;
    if (req.session.entityId) entityId = req.session.entityId;
    if (req.session.deviceId) deviceId = req.session.deviceId;

    res.render('error/illegal', {
        title: 'Illegal'
        , viewClass: 'illegal'
        , ngController : ''
        , entityName : entityName
        , entityId : entityId
        , deviceId : deviceId
        , authorizationLevel : authLevel
    });
};
```

**routes.dashboard**

Which works well too when you load it from the URL

```
exports.dashboard = function(req, res){
    //Method for authorization, see below. This is giving me error.
    authorizationHelper.authorizationLevels(req, res, 400);

    var authLevel = '';
    var entityName = '';
    var entityId = '';
    var deviceId = '';

    if (req.session.authorizationLevel) authLevel = req.session.authorizationLevel;
    if (req.session.name) entityName = req.session.name;
    if (req.session.entityId) entityId = req.session.entityId;
    if (req.session.deviceId) deviceId = req.session.deviceId;

    res.render('dashboard', {
        title: 'Dashboard'
        , viewClass: 'dashboard'
        , ngController: 'dashboardController'
        , entityName : entityName
        , entityId : entityId
        , deviceId : deviceId
        , authorizationLevel : authLevel
    });

};
```

Here's the tricky part that is giving me some error.

```
    //Method for authorization, see below. This is giving me error.
    authorizationHelper.authorizationLevels(req, res, 400);
```

**authorizationHelper**

This method will check if user is allowed to view the page, else it will redirect

```
exports.authorizationLevels = function(req, res, levelRequired){
    if (req.session.authorizationLevel < levelRequired || !req.session.authorizationLevel){
        //user is not allowed to view the page, redirect to illegal page
        res.redirect('/error/401');
    }
}
```

The problem is, everything works fine from the top to this res.redirect('/error/401') and sometimes, on the server, it will not render the page but instead, it will render a whole bunch of HTML text and *some headers!!*!

[image]

Please help!

Comment: Is the HTML shown your `dashboard` template?

Comment: Yes, it is my dashboard template. I am using express-ejs-layout for my rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You could change

```
exports.authorizationLevels = function(req, res, levelRequired) {
  if (req.session.authorizationLevel < levelRequired || !req.session.authorizationLevel){
      //user is not allowed to view the page, redirect to illegal page
      res.redirect('/error/401');
  }
}
```

to

```
exports.authorizationLevels = function(req, res, levelRequired) {
  if (req.session.authorizationLevel < levelRequired || !req.session.authorizationLevel){
      //user is not allowed to view the page, redirect to illegal page
      res.redirect('/error/401');
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

and

```
authorizationHelper.authorizationLevels(req, res, 400);
```

to

```
if (!authorizationHelper.authorizationLevels(req, res, 400))
  return;
```

That will prevent the rendering of your dashboard in case of unauthorized access.

Also, you might consider centralizing your error handling so that you just install an error handler middleware (`(err, req, res, next)`) and do your error template rendering there (while simply doing `next(401);` and such on errors in your route handlers), unless you want them to see the `/error/401` and such URLs in the browser.